# Accessing nested object within array in PHP (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, object, nested

I am struggling for quite a while on how to access nested object.

```
    $dt = Carbon::parse($year.'-'.$month.'-1');
    $godziny = array();
    $gs = $lekarz->od;
    $gz = $lekarz->do;
    $ile = $gz-$gs;
    for($j=0; $j<4*$ile; $j++){
        if($j%4==0){
            $wm = "00";
        }
        else{
            $wm = ($j%4)*15;
        }
        if($gs+floor(($j/4)) < 10){
            $dz="0".$dz = $gs+floor(($j/4));
        } else{
            $dz = $gs+floor(($j/4));
        }
        $godziny[$j]['godzina'] = $dz;
        $godziny[$j]['minuty'] = $wm;
        if(!empty(Kolejka::where('data', 'LIKE', $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day.' '.$dz.':'.$wm.'%')->get())){
            $godziny[$j]['odbyta'] = Kolejka::where('data', 'LIKE', $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day.' '.$dz.':'.$wm.'%')->get();
            dd(get_object_vars($godziny[$j]['odbyta']));
           // $godziny[$j]['pacjent'] = Pacjent::where('id', '=', $godziny[$j]['odbyta']->{0}->pacjent_id);
        } else { 
            $godziny[$j]['odbyta'] = '';
        }
    }
```

Everything works except for the last part. It seems like whatever way i try to access this data ( by using $godziny[$j]['odbyta']['pacjent_id'] or by $godziny[$j]['odbyta']->pacjent_id) it just won't work. I really don't know what to do.

That's my [$j]['odbyta] data:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "pacjent_id": "13",
    "lekarz_id": "1",
    "data": "2017-04-05 10:15:00",
    "odbyta": "0",
    "created_at": "2017-04-05 16:14:42",
    "updated_at": "2017-04-05 16:14:42"
}
```

That is code that generates data with a pattern:
$j's max number is 36

```
$godziny[0]['godzina'] = $dz //That's for setting hour to array
$godziny[0]['godzina'] = $wm; //That's for assigning minutes
$godziny[0]['odbyta'] <- that's of value of object that i listed above
```

How can i possibly access data from this object? 
so $godziny[0]['odbyta'] can give me an value of object it contains?

Comment: We need just a bit more info, the data you posted did you do a json_encode on it, or is that how it is natively?

Comment: Laravel is encoding everything to json by default. What data specifically do you need?

Comment: That's why it's not working, you need to `json_decode()` it when you store it or goto read it.

Comment: I misunderstood how this works. It's not json. Everything works. I can get this object displayed but i cannot access any of it's data :x

Comment: Hard to determine what the problem is you haven't given enough code. How is `$j` set? Looks like some kind of iterator variable.

Comment: Lemme reedit question and be more specific

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: I have no idea what `Kolejka` is, nor can I find any documentation that's easy to find for it, so I have no idea what kind of data you are getting. if you just `var_dump($godziny[0]['odbyta'])` what do you get?

Comment: also instead of running that query twice you should run it once, by doing it in a variable and if it's not empty store the variable.

Comment: Kolejka is Model that stands for database request to acquire data. Response of it is back in question. That's what i got after var_dumb: 

http://screenshot.sh/mMhVI77wblzqq (sorry for screenshot but it's 2 long to post there)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-collections this should give you the info that you're looking for then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just use Model->where...first()? and than access it as object:

```
$godziny[$j]['odbyta'] = Kolejka::where('data', 'LIKE', $year.'-'.$month.'-'.$day.' '.$dz.':'.$wm.'%')->first();
$godziny[$j]['pacjent'] = Pacjent::where('id', '=', $godziny[$j]['odbyta']->pacjent_id);
```

Comment: I need to access "attributes" from this:

Comment: `Kolejka {#235 ▼
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:7 [▼
    "id" => "1"
    "pacjent_id" => "13"
    "lekarz_id" => "1"
    "data" => "2017-04-05 09:00:00"
    "odbyta" => "0"
    "created_at" => "2017-04-05 16:14:42"
    "updated_at" => "2017-04-05 16:14:42"
  ]
  #original: array:7 [▶]
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
...`

Comment: When you do  $godziny[$j]['odbyta']->pacjent_id the model will access the "attributes" param through magic methods, did you try to copy and paste the code i provided in my answer? it didn't work?

Comment: I used pluck function to accomplish this task